# Is it possible to attack underwater?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, my character is an Argonian and I swim a lot and I keep getting attacked by slaughterfish underwater.  I don't appear to be able to use my weapons or magic while underwater.

Is there anything in the game that would let me kill those stupid fish while I am underwater with them?

They don't ever kill me but they are annoying and should be murdered like ever other creature I find the in wilderness!

Comment: The cloak spells in the destruction line comes to mind, not sure if they still work while underwater though.

Comment: You can lure them into shallow water, and attack them then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@RavenDreamer is correct.  You cannot perform any attack underwater without a mod / using a console command.  Your best efforts would be to do what Raven Dreamer said, lure them to shallow water and then attack them.

For underwater abilities: There are potions that allow you to breathe longer underwater and you can also catch fish / harvest ingredients while underwater.

Comment: I'm an Argonian so they can do underwater breathing as a racial bonus.  I'll lure those fish into the shallows and shoot them with a bow or something.  One way or another, those fish are going to get it!

Comment: @TheSasquatch +1 for your relentlessness but hate is the path of the dark side! ;-)

Answer (score 15):

@yx has the right idea.  A flame cloak is an awesome way to deal with slaughterfish.  They do indeed work underwater, and will kill a slaughterfish in about 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Good ideas all around here.  My preferred method is shooting in Fireballs from the shore.  It's like fishing with dynamite.

Answer (score 4):

You may find the [Ebony Mail](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Mail_(Skyrim)) with its constant poison AoE damage quite useful for this, as well as an excellent piece of armor in general. Level 30 required. It appears to do 5 damage per second.

The [Flame Cloak](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Flame_Cloak) mentioned in another answer does 8, and thus may be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the drain vitality spell from land in their general direction, then go in the water to get it to track you (shows up as red enemy dot), then you can attack and kill with ranged from land.  At least, that's how I do it in the hatchery...